# Why this two seemingly same declarations results in different string length?

Tags: c, initialization, declaration, string-length

Can anyone explain why this code:

```
char    t1[20];
char    t2[20];

memset(t1, 'B', sizeof(t1));
memset(t2, 'B', sizeof(t2));
printf("%lu\n", strlen(t1));
printf("%lu\n", strlen(t2));
```

result in:

```
22
21
```

Thank's

Comment: Note that both the lengths you get are longer than the actual arrays... you don't have a null char in the arrays to mark the end of the string, so `strlen()` keeps going 'til it finds one (past the end of the array somewhere).

Comment: Because you haven't null terminated either string, so you get garbage results.

Comment: cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: `strlen()` returns a result of type `size_t`. Use `"%zu"`, not `"%lu"`, to print it. (If your implementation doesn't support `"%zu"`, you'll need to cast the value to an appropriate type.)

Comment: You forgot to null-terminate your strings, so `strlen` is running past the end resulting in undefined behavior.  Fix your bugs, *then* ask questions if you still don't understand.

Comment: You can initialise a `char`-array  to all zeros by doing `char a[42] = "";`.

Answer (score 1):

[`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) expects to be given a (pointer to a) *C string*. A C string is an array of `char` **terminated with the null character, `'\0'`**.

When you `memset` your `char` arrays, you just write a `'B'` into every element, thus neither of these arrays is a C string. Passing them to `strlen` is undefined behavior.

In order to fix this, set the last element of each array accordingly:

```
t1[19] = '\0';
t2[19] = '\0';
```

Comment: Interesting enough, different compilers seem to implement `memset` differently. llvm clang seems to put trailing `\0', whereas gcc doesn't. In any case you save yourself a lot of trouble if you 'null terminate' the C strings programmatically.

Comment: @user3078414 That's a false assumption: clang certainly does **not** put a trailing `'\0'`. What you're most likely witnessing is a combination of zero'd stack space and some sort of alignment (64 bit machine?), so that there is actually a null byte **after** the end of the arrays.

Comment: To be accurate, this "*`strlen` expects to be given a (pointer to a) *C string*.*" should read "*`strlen` expects to be given a (pointer to the first element of a) *C string*.*"

Comment: @Daniel Jour. I didn't mean to challenge your expert knowledge. Yet a heretic question is here: how come there is a `null byte`-effect in the end of the arrays created using `clang`, whereas none using `gcc` **on the same machine**, same OS?  I could consistently reproduce the problem.